# Excluding elements in XQuery

Tags: xml, filter, for-loop, xquery

I have an XML element such as:

```
<items>
   <item>
      <size>360</size>
      <quantity>400</quantity>
   <item>
   <item>
      <size>540</size>
      <quantity>1200</quantity>
   <item>
   <item>
      <size>360</size>
      <quantity>600</quantity>
   <item>
   <item>
      <size>800</size>
      <quantity>750</quantity>
   <item>
</items>
```

What I need to do is iterate over this element and pull out ONLY the first item elements with a distinct size element. So I want to have:

```
<item>
  <size>360</size>
  <quantity>400</quantity>
<item>
<item>
   <size>540</size>
   <quantity>1200</quantity>
<item>
<item>
   <size>800</size>
   <quantity>750</quantity>
<item>
```

Removing the second item element with a size of 360. Is there a way of filtering these out in a for loop filter statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is:

```
for $item in $items
where $item is $items[size = $item/size][1]
return $item
```

another is

```
let $sizes = distinct-values($items/size)
for $size in $sizes
return $items[size = $size][1]
```

and yet another (more evil) way is

```
$items[index-of($items/size, size)[1]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the following query helping?

```
for $item in $items
let $size := number($item/size/text()) 
return
  if($size != 360) then
    $item
  else ()
```

Comment: I believe this would exclude all elements with size of 360 not just the 2nd - nth. Plus the value could sometimes be something other than 360, which is unknown at this point.